# How to validate user input with try and catch?

Tags: java, validation, integer, try-catch, infinite-loop

I need to write a program that can validate user input as integer and prevent it from crashing whenever use input is not integer. So I am using `try` and `catch` here. However, I got an infinite loop when user input is a non-integer. Below is my code

```
do {
    try {
        a = sc.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchExpression e) {
        System.out.println("This is not integer");
    }
} while(a < 1 || a > 10);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the Scanner throws an exception, the existing value remains "unconsumed". To avoid this you need to add sc.next() line to consume the existing input and make Scanner await the next value from the user.

```
do {
    try {
        a = sc.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchExpression e) {

        sc.next(); // this "consumes" the invalid input and throws away

        System.out.println("This is not integer");
    }
} while(a < 1 || a > 10);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So sc.next() serves as discarding input too?  other time it will serve as taking user input (String)?

Comment: This is still the same method reading a line. Just because we don't need the String value we call the method without the assignment.
```String inputWeDontNeed = sc.next(); ``` would also work.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to break the loop, if user input is a non-integer, then you can simply add a flag value in your code :

```
int flag = 0;
do {
try {
    a = sc.nextInt();
} catch (InputMismatchExpression e) {
    System.out.println("This is not integer");
flag=1;
}
} while((a < 1 || a > 10)&&flag==0);
```

If flag=1, loop will break.

Comment: 1. `flag` should be a boolean. 2. Using exceptions for input validation is normally considered bad style and in the general could cause performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

normaly use regex check user input
like :

```
String userInput = "1234567";
boolean isNumber = userInput.matches("^\\d+$");
System.out.println(isNumber);
```